# Wp child theme function can't redecalre function error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the wordpress site.

I used the child theme. After wordpress upgrade I received the following error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function name() (previously declared...
```

If I removed the function code it shows error for next function...

It shows the eror only  the files which I include `include("../../../wp-load.php");`

I used some direct files Here I directly include the `wp-load file`

For these files it shows the error. If I convert these files as Template file then it working fine.

I don't know why the error occurs. Please help me.

Below is the code I used in my file

```
<?php
ob_start();
error_reporting(0);
 include("../../../wp-load.php");

global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;

$fp_secquestion = $_REQUEST['fp_secquestion'];//'aaa';
$fp_secanswer = $_REQUEST['fp_secanswer'];//'aaa';
$fp_email = $_REQUEST['fp_email'];//'testuser5@st.com';




$user_login = sanitize_text_field($user_login);

if (empty( $fp_secquestion) || empty( $fp_secanswer) || empty( $fp_email)  ) {
    $log = 'validerr';

} else  {
    $user_data = get_user_by( 'email', trim( $fp_email ) );
    if ( empty( $user_data ) )
       $log = 'err';
} 

echo $log;
```

Comment: Is the child theme actually including the wp-load.php file?

Comment: @Nick Duncan: I have update my code here.

Comment: You really shouldnt be loading wp-load.php like that. Why not just wrap this code in your functions.php of your child theme as a function and use a $_GET variable to access and print out that function?

Comment: I used a ajax call in the button click. For this I created the file 'test.php'. In this file I used the above code. In ajax post url I called this "test.php". Here It shows error.